# Backbone get() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backbone.js, underscore.js

Problem lies in the PostRouter var in app.js file. Logging this.posts.toJSON() returns the data in my DB but calling get passing the id returns undefined. The routing works as the id is passed in the url and is logged in my function. I am using Mongo to store data and Monk to query the db.

My server file

```
//configure
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.json()); //parses the JSON requests being sent to the server
    app.use(express.static( path.join(__dirname, 'public') )); //serve files from the path given
});

app.get("/posts", function(req, res){
    var db = req.db;

    db.get("postscollection").find({}, function (err, results) {
        res.json(results);
    });
});

//create route using Express REST API
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    var db = req.db;

    db.get("postscollection").find({}, function (err, results) {
        res.render("index.ejs", { posts: JSON.stringify(results) }); //pass object of values to use in template
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

My app file

```
//Post
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({});

//Posts
var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Post,
        url: "/posts"
    });

//PostListView
var PostListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    template: _.template("<a href='/posts/{{_id}}'>{{title}}</a>"),

    render: function () {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template(this.model.toJSON()); //this.model is view instance
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        'click a': 'handleClick'
    },

    handleClick: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        postRouter.navigate($(e.currentTarget).attr("href"), { trigger: true }); //navigate to specified route and trigger routing
    }
});

//PostsListView
var PostsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("<h1>My Blog</h1><ul></ul>"),

    render: function () {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template();

        var ul = this.$el.find("ul"); //this.$el == $(el)

        this.collection.forEach(function (post) {
            ul.append(new PostListView({ model: post }).render().el);
        });

        return this;
    }
});

//PostView
var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({        
    events: {
        'click a': 'handleClick'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.template = _.template($("#postView").html()); //to prevent template from loading before scripts
    },

    render: function () {
        var model = this.model.toJSON();

        this.el.innerHTML = this.template(model);

        return this;
    },

    handleClick: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        postRouter.navigate($(e.currentTarget).attr("href"), {trigger: true});
    }
});

//PostRouter
var PostRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.posts = options.posts; //the posts collection
        this.main  = options.main; //the main id div in the view
    },

    routes: {
        ''         : 'index',
        'posts/:id': 'singlePost'
    },

    index: function () {
        var pv = new PostsListView({ collection: this.posts });
        this.main.html(pv.render().el);
    },

    singlePost: function (id) {    
        console.log("view post " + id); //logs id passed
        console.log(this.posts.toJSON()); //logs data in db

        var post = this.posts.get(id); //returns undefined
        var pv = new PostView({ model: post });

        this.main.html(pv.render().el);
    }
});
```

The index works fine and display all my data but trying to view individual posts breaks the application.

Comment: Maybe you are passing in wrong id... We don't know. Please create a [mcve] with sample data.

Comment: Apparently the mongo generated IDs for entries was not being set on my models. I had to set the idAttribute of the model to be "_id"